# Aura:if condition check

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can i check the following in aura

```
<aura:if istrue="{!v.flag<2}">
</aura:if>
```

I want to check whether the value of flag is less than 2 but i am getting error.

```
Failed to save undefined: markup://c:SFDC_Ltng_Stakeholder:230,49: ParseError at [row,col]:[231,49] Message: The value of attribute "istrue" associated with an element type "aura:if" must not contain the '<' character.: Source
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try with `greaterthan` function

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm

```
<aura:if istrue="{!greaterthan(v.flag,2)}">
</aura:if>
```

Comment: I think it should be less than according to my requirement.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal ok you can use `lessthan` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.flag < 2}">

</aura:if>
```

For True condition, set attribute value as below in application,

```
<aura:application >
    <c:ConditionalComponent edit="true"/>
</aura:application>
```

For False condition, set attribute value as below in your application,

```
<aura:application >
    <c:ConditionalComponent edit="false"/>
</aura:application>
```